# Are REST services and security/authentication not antithetical?

Tags: rest, security, authentication

I am having a hard time reconciling the idea of a browser based javascript application that requires authentication to be implemented with a (by-the-book) REST service as backend.

1. REST services should be stateless
2. Cookies/sessions are stateful
3. All other authentication schemes are basically insecure

   - Basic Authentication is insecure because it requires the password to be stored in the js application, where it can easily be stolen by other scripts/extensions.
   - Any kind of token scheme suffers from essentially the same problem, the token can easily be retrieved by other scripts/extensions
   - Furthermore, any token scheme used should not transmit the token in the URL, as that is insecure. So the token must be transmitted via POST or other HTTP method, but that again violates REST principles for GET request (i.e. you should use GET to read data, not POST).

So if I am really concerned about security, isn't the most secure scheme not a cookie/session based approach? And does that not preclude using a REST service backend?

It seems to me that REST services are still popular, so am I overthinking things?

**EDIT:** I am looking for a clear-cut answer that

- either confirms that true-by-the-book-REST-service is incompatible with maximizing security in a general case
- or describes how to overcome these challenges so that the REST service can both be used with maximum security (i.e. does not present more risks than non-REST solutions) while staying 100% true to the REST principles.
- or describes the required conditions for a scenario where a 100% true REST service is no less secure than alternatives (for example: "requires end-user browser to be locked down with no extensions allowed")

Answer (score 1):

This might be opinionated, but statelessness is overrated. Most services don't actually need to be stateless, your are likely not developing the next big hit with 10 million concurrent users. From a pure security perspective, statelessness brings problems like token invalidation (ie. logout) being practically impossible.

Also stateful REST is not unheard of. For the reasons above, in many cases it makes a lot of sense to have a stateful backend to maintain user sessions while also adhering to most REST principles. Many times an API gateway-like component provides state, and all the services behind it can then be stateless. This in fact is probably the most secure architecture you can get for many applications, because backend services can scale, but it also provides the frontend state for features like session invalidation.

You can also mix these, which is an often used thing. You can have an identity provider on its own origin  like login.example.com where you issue tokens, and this identity provider can be stateful (ie. use cookies for refresh token or session id storage). And then you can have stateless services on api.example.com which consume these tokens statelessly. You are right that tokens are then susceptible to XSS, but that is often a tradeoff, smart risk if you like that can be mitigated by a very limited token lifetime for example (which helps, because XSS many times needs user interaction, so even if the attacker could get hold of one token, it's still not automatic the next time).

So in short, it all depends on what risks you want to accept, and what business requirements you need to fulfill. And even if you go stateful, you don't need to ditch REST in general.

(Also, using request headers for tokens in GET requests is not at all against REST or the HTTP standard).

Comment: My thoughts match up very much with yours, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Wrt your edit, there is no such thing as security in an absolute sense. There are threats, some of which are relevant to a specific case, some are less so. Some you decide to mitigate, by implementing software in a certain way. There will always be risks you accept, consciously in the better case, or just because you didn't even think of them. With using 100% REST, you do accept certain threats. That doesn't mean it is insecure, it's a decision you made, hopefully by understanding what you are accepting. Sometimes it makes sense, for other applications it probably doesn't.

Comment: That is why I wrote "maximum security". I realize that security can never be complete, but you can try to minimize the number of risks. And yes, different situations may have different risks associated, but I am looking for an answer that reduces the total number of risks in a general situation where you cannot exclude any risk factors. Or at the very least, an answer that is explicit about which risk factors are present.